# Can't change Nagare App

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I've tried to make some changes to [Nagare for Android](https://github.com/Dawnthorn/nagare), to see if I could fix the audio skipping during playback. I was surprised that none of my changes take effect, now I noticed the reason in the console:

```
[2013-01-09 07:46:27 - Nagare] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2013-01-09 07:46:27 - Nagare] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2.2)
[2013-01-09 07:46:27 - Nagare] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-01-09 07:46:27 - Nagare] Starting activity com.giantrabbit.nagare.Nagare on device ...
```

I have made some changes, saved, cleaned projects, updated Android SDK, restarted Eclipse, restarted computer... why does it not let me build changes?

Even if I comment out all the onCreate code, if I set it to debug there, it steps through the commented-out code. So, something must be wrong with the compiler?

Comment: Have you incremented the version code in your manifest?

Comment: I tried that, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the application and clean all application data. Than install again. This will leave no chance for the same situation to happen. Than if anything appears afterwards it would be a new problem.

Update: Try changing the workspace and check out again, recompile and please tell us what happened.

Comment: Update: Try changing the workspace and check out again, recompile and please tell us what happened. Same result?